# Adding new column in table from UI input

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to web Applications and trying to make a simple web application using `php` and `Mysql`.
I have created a table named `Item` having 2 column `pen` and `pencil`.
For each user I am inserting values in these two columns.
Suppose In future I got a new Item `sharpner` from UI.
I want to create a new column automatically in this `Item` table every time I got a new item from UI.
I am searching for any library or tool using that I will able to do this.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  Why do you want to dynamically change the database schema?  If there are new "items" that can be added, then have an "item_types" table in which you'd insert a new *row* for a new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a new column automatically

No you don't.

You've defined two entities.  An instance of an item, and a *type* of an item.  Create a table for each:

```
item_type
----------
ID
Name

item
----------
ID
ItemTypeID
[other data you're tracking]
```

The `item.ItemTypeID` column would be a foreign key to the `item_type` table.

When a user adds a new "item type", you add a new record to the `item_type` table.  You're then free to add instances of that type of item to the `item` table.

In the *vast* majority of cases, dynamically modifying your *schema* isn't what you want.  Define the structure of the data you want to track and build that structure.  Then simply add/modify/remove *records* of that data.  Don't re-structure the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by David there is better design in relational database world. However if your application is essentially requires some sort of dynamic schema, you might consider using Document - oriented database such as MongoDB or Couch.